# Similar random variation for two columns in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
data = pd.DataFrame(1.0, index=[1,2,3,4,5], columns=list('ABCD') )
data[['B', 'C']] = data[['B', 'C']].apply(lambda x: x + (-1)**random.randrange(2)*1)
```

I wanted to randomly vary column B and C, such that the the variation is the same for both columns. If column B increase by one, column C must increase by one too. however for each row, the value can increase/decrease randomly. Code above doesn't work. Then I tried this with random seed:

```
data['B'] = data['B'].apply(lambda x: x + (-1)**random.randrange(2)*1)
data['C'] = data['C'].apply(lambda x: x + (-1)**random.randrange(2)*1)
```

Each rows vary randomly but the change in column B and C are not the same. how do I do this?

expected output

```
    A   B   C   D
1   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
2   1.0 2.0 2.0 1.0
3   1.0 2.0 2.0 1.0
4   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
5   1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
```

Comment: I'd make a frame with one column the random variation, the size of your data, and added them. first to one column, then to the other column. Also, check [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply) that apparently can operate on whole series (sets of columns).

Comment: that should work, thank you!